# Receiving response code 500 when trying to open a webpage using Appium on Android Emulated Device

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

Based on the following code:

```
@Test
public void androidDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    driver.get("website");
}
```

I am receiving the following errors:

IDE Error:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools'?
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'LAP3-056', ip: '192.168.68.102', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, platformName: android}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: emulator-5554, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 11}}]
Capabilities {}
```

I am using the latest version of Appium Server GUI and Android SDK Platform-Tools is also installed.

Any other ideas of what can I do to fix this?

Comment: The error is showing multiple locations where it's not able to find apksigner.jar file. Did you check all these locations and confirm that the file is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the apksigner was not there, hence adding it manually based on [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878903/receiving-response-code-500-when-trying-to-open-a-webpage-using-appium-on-androi/74901905#comment132155576_74878903) by @Omprakash Chavan fixed the issue.